# developing an android login system

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, registration

this is my first time developing an android application and i'm trying to make a login system for my android Alarm app on eclipse. I want the user to be able to login to the app or  to register as new user. and depending on the type of user he/she will be authenticated to some part (views) of the app. for example i want to have two types of users stored in SQLite: Admin, and a regular user
the admin will have a different view of the app than the regular user after they login.
How would I do this ? is there any suggested books that explains it, good online tutorials, or help from you?
It would be easier if android had a source code for this kind of thing.
I have no idea how to do this

Best Regards,
zoza

Answer (score 0):

Create two different activities for normal user and admin. After proper authentication based on the values given in the EditText in the login page launch needed activity by calling Intent.

```
Intent ActivityIn = new Intent(this, User.class);
//If you have some value to passed
ActivityIn.putExtra("userId", value);
startActivity(ActivityIn);
```

Hope this is what you wanted.This link will help you to know more about Intents.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: thanks but my point is how to check the validity of the username and its password according to its type and correctness in order to move the desired activity. i know how to move to another activity but checking the username and password in SQLite is the thing that i don't know how to do it.